# Better way to refer to structure size( #pragma pack VS defined size )

Tags: c++, struct

Assume I have the struct Foo

```
struct Foo{
    int a;
    short b;
    char  c;
};
```

And I has to write this struct in to n/w buffer. I need to know the size of this struct.
In my environment, sizeof(Foo) returns 8, That's ok, I understand.

These are two way to refer to the exact size that I want to write to the buffer

1.`#define SIZEOF_FOO 7`, And use this instead of `sizeof(Foo)`
2. By using `#pragma pack` so I can use `sizeof(Foo)` which will return 7

Which one is the better way to do, or Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: What's you intention? To know the size of Foo at any time, or force the size of Foo to of some certain value? Indeed, sizeof(Foo) returns the actual size of Foo, and your expectation of it to be 7 is wrong. You must write the actual number of bytes to the buffer, not the number you wish the structure to be. Also, using any constants won't guarantee that both the sender and the recipient have the same size of Foo.

Comment: Well, The point is the receiver is in the different system, and it expect the first 4 bytes to be "a" value, and so on, next 2 bytes is "b", next 1 byte is c. It's the problem when it add padding 0 after "c" regarding the writing size 8 (from sizeof) instead of 7. And it corrupt the buffer stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to write out such a structure to a network, please use a protocol framework or marshal the data explicitly using a protocol you define independent of the structure layout.

Depending on the binary layout details of a structure will likely cause pain down the road.

I've heard good things about [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) and [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), but I haven't used either.

I've dealt with a protocol defined in a document, and output the data according to that protocol using custom marshaling routines, or used an IDL description (which is kind of like an annotated C structure that used to drive a code generator that crates the serialization/deserialization routines).

That way you (or the protocol framework) control the use of padding regardless of what the compiler does to the structure.  Note that is you use a protocol framework, you typically need to use it on both ends (which might be a problem if the other node is out of your control or an embedded device which the framework doesn't support, for example).

Answer (score 0):

The `#pragma pack` directive modifies the current alignment rule for members of structures following the directive. Hence, it affects the size of structs defined **after** the pragma!

You most likely don't need this. **Just use `sizeof(Foo)` wherever you want to know the size of your struct.** And don't write pragmas, as they are used in some special cases!

You can see these links to know in details about pragmas:

[GCC - Structure-Packing Pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html)
[MSVC++ - Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
[pragma pack](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Frnpgpack.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This question is severely misguided. The size of `Foo` is always whatever `sizeof(Foo)` returns. Do not assume, do not use wishful thinking, use `sizeof`.

In fact, I would expect `sizeof(Foo)` to be 12, aligning everything on a 4-byte boundary.

Either way, the good news is that `sizeof` is resolved at compile time, and has absolutely no impact on performance. So, there's no reason not to use it.

```
#define SIZEOF_FOO (sizeof(Foo))
```

Comment: Just curious: Why do you expect it to be 9?

Comment: I expect `sizeof(Foo)` to be 8, as 'short' and 'char' would accommodate within 4 byte boundary!

Comment: I initially had 12, but trimmed it to 9 because I was being stupid. I've re-edited it to 12.

Comment: If you define `struct Foo{ short b; int a; char  c;};` OR `struct Foo{ char c; int a; short b;};`..  means, as long as `int a` comes between short and char, sizeof(Foo) would be 12.

Comment: "I've re-edited it to 12"... No, it wouldn't be 12 if the compiler is smart enough. See my other comments!

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to write structure by sequential writing its members. E.g. you can use boost serialization.

This will separate representation of the structure in application memory from format used for transmission.

Answer (score 0):

`#define SIZEOF_FOO 7` without using `#pragma pack` should not be used at all. The reason being, when you call `send` (or any equivalent) function passing a variable of your struct type and pass the data size as `7`, the send function will send only the first `7` bytes of data, and when you receive this data at the other end, you will definitely mess a  lot of things in your code.

Using `#pragma pack` directives will change the alignment of member of your struct amd you will certainly save a few bytes of data over network transfer, but if you think in terms of optimization/performance, these few bytes are negligible. Although, most of the applications (that I have seen) use `#pragma pack` for packing struct members, but that totally depends on your requirement.

One major problem with using a `#define SIZEOF_FOO 7` is that, if you port your code to some other platform/architecture, the actual size of your structure might not be same (7 bytes) and then you will either have to use a platform dependent macro or come up with some other alternative.

So in short, you should always use `sizeof` instead of using `#define SIZEOF_FOO`.